# Add dynamic error message to custom regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have built a custom regular expression class. I also have a database value that is a list of characters that I don't want to be allowed anywhere in my web application. My custom regular expression class will take all other regular expressions and ensure that my list of unwanted characters are not allowed. My custom regular expression class is register in my Global.asax.cs and since it is a value in the database it can be changed when deemed necessary. Now what I need to do is find a way to take the regex error message and add on to it with something like: "This field cannot contain the following: " + mybadcharacterlist;

Already tried this:

public const string AlphaErrMsg = "This field can only contain letters. This field cannot include the following characters: " + RestrictedCharacterList.GetList();

Which didn't work because the error parameter for RegularExpressionAttribute requires a const and calling my GetList method isn't a constant.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof   (RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute), typeof(RegulatExpressionAttributeAdapter);
}
```

```
public class RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute(string propRegex) : base(GetRegex(propRegex)) {}

    private static string GetRegex(string propRegex)
    {
        in indexPropRegex = propRegex.IndexOf('^');
        string restrictedCharsAction = "(?!.*[" + RestrictedCharacterList.GetList() + "])";
        propRegex = indexPropRegex == -1 ? propRegex.Insert(0, restrictedCharsAction) : propRegex.Insert(indexPropRegex + 1, restrictedCharsAction);
        return propRegex;
    }
}
```

```
public static class RestrictedCharacterList
{
    public static string GetList()
    {
         string restrictedChars;
         if (HttpContext.Current?.Session == null)
         {
             restrictedChars = EnvironmentSettingsDA.GetSetting(AppConfiguration.Settings.ConnectionString, "CAMPS", "RESTRICTED_CHARACTERS");
         }
         else
         {
             restrictedChars = HttpContext.Current.Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("RESTRICTED_CHARACTERS");
             if (restrictedChars == null)
             {
                 restrictedChars = EnvironmentSettingsDA.GetSetting(AppConfiguration.Settings.ConnectionString, "CAMPS", "RESTRICTED_CHARACTERS");
                 HttpContext.Current.Session.SetDataToSession<string>("Restricted_Characters", restrictedChars);
             }
         }
    return restrictedChars;
    }
}
```

```
public class User 
{
    public const string IsAlphaRegex = "^[a-zA-Z]*$'

    public const string AlphaErrMsg = "This field can only contain letters.";

    [RestrictCharRegExpress(IsAlphaRegex, ErrorMessage = AlphaErrMsg)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

The expected results would be to add a message to all my regex error messages describing what characters are not allowed while ensuring that list of characters can be changed in the database.

Comment: Note `"^[a-zA-Z]*$` should end with `"`. The chars in a character list thag need escaping are ``\``, `]`, `^` and `-`. So, use `RestrictedCharacterList.GetList().Replace("^","\\^")).Replace("\\","\\\\")).Replace("]","\\]")).Replace("-","\\-")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For some reason I don't have to do that. Maybe C# escapes them itself when the characters are pulled from the database? Either way I haven't had to do any special replace commands.

Comment: Then you end up with corrupt patterns that match something different from what you expect.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This comment is for anyone else who might see this page in the future. Wiktor you are completely right and I am wrong. I didn't have any issues before because I wasn't trying to exclude those characters, but then they needed to block backslash and it didn't work. I included what you suggested and it worked correctly. So thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to Reviews Alot for leading me down the right path but this is what I did to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Added the following to RestrictedCharacterList class:

```
public static class RestrictedCharacterList
{
    public static string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return " Valid values cannot include the following restricted characters: " + GetList();
    }
}
```

Added the following to RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute class:

```
public class RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public string AddToRestrictCharErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        if (string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(AddToRestrictedCharErrorMessage))
        {
            return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
        }
        else
        {
            return AddToRestrctCharErrorMessage + " " + RestrictedCharacterList.GetErrorMessage():
        }
    }
}
```

And then when you want the special character message appended to an existing error message you assign the data attribute like so:

```
public class User 
{
    public const string IsAlphaRegex = "^[a-zA-Z]*$'

    public const string AlphaErrMsg = "This field can only contain letters.";

    [RestrictCharRegExpress(IsAlphaRegex, AddToRestrictCharErrorMessage = AlphaErrMsg)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do this is to override FormatErrorMessage in RestrictCharRegExprAttribute:

```
public class RestrictCharRegExprAttribute: RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute(string propRegex): base( GetRegex(propRegex)
    {
         this.Message = ...; // localized message
    }

    private string Message { get; }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string propertyName)
    {
        return this.Message; 
    }

}
```

Comment: So how would I add on to the existing error message instead of over writing it with the localized message? This method will only display the localized message. Another way to put it is that this will only display  "This field cannot include the following characters: 123" vs  "This field can only contain letters. This field cannot include the following characters: 123"

Comment: Just call the base.FormatErrorMessage and spend whatever you would like.